# Is the Fourier transform of the function correct?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am asked to calculate the Fourier transform of the function $$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}}, a>0$$
$$$$
After calculations I have found the following:
$$a \sqrt{2 \pi}  e^{-\frac{a^2 k^2}{2}}$$
$$$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Depends on which definition of Fourier transform you use; there are several versions of it.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills I use this definition: $$\widetilde{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(x)e^{-ikx}}dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Wolfram|Alpha with FourierParameters](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fouriertransform%5Be%5E%28-x%5E2/%282a%5E2%29%29,%20x,%20k,%20FourierParameters%20-%3E%20%7B1,%20-1%7D%5D&x=0&y=0) to specify your version of the Fourier Transform.

In short: your result is correct.